# How do I access an Access database protected by a username/password in Access workgroups via Jet?

Tags: c#

I found [this page](http://www.carlprothman.net/Default.aspx?tabid=87#OLEDBProviderForMicrosoftJet) which suggested adding the "Jet OLEDB:System Database" item to my connection string, and then providing a username and password parameter to `Open`. Unfortuanately, it seems the .NET OleDb classes don't seem to have this... I tried the following code just incase:

```
testConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + mdbFile + 
    ";Jet OLEDB:System Database=" + Path.GetDirectoryName(mdbFile) + "\\system.mdw;" + 
    "Jet OLEDB:System Username=***;Jet OLEDB:System Password=***");
```

But this just seems to hang for a long time before throwing a "Could not find installable ISAM" `DbException`.

Does anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT:** I tried using the following connection string, which stopped the exception, but didn't let me access any tables, like what happens when I open Access without the workgroup setup properly.

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + mdbFile +
";Jet OLEDB:System Database=" + Path.GetDirectoryName(mdbFile) + "\\system.mdw;" +
"User ID=***;Password=***";
```

Comment: Take a look at the various different connection string variations at http://www.connectionstrings.com for connecting to Access to see if any of those work.

Comment: The fourth one on the list here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/access is the one I'm already using, and it isn't working.

Comment: Alright, yes it is working. Looks like it really is my SQL that needs work... The question is why, since the query works in Access directly...

Comment: Whadda you know, Jet uses `%` as a `LIKE` wildcard, but Access uses `*`. GAH. Someone kick me if I ever volunteer to work on legacy systems again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like an idiot now, but scrolling up a bit on that page accidentally, I noticed some of the connection strings  had a "User ID" and "Password" parameters. Changing the connection string to use these instead of trying to pass them to "Jet OLEDB:*" fixed the issue.

ie, my final connection string was:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + mdbFile +
";Jet OLEDB:System Database=" + Path.GetDirectoryName(mdbFile) + "\\system.mdw;" +
"User ID=***;Password=***";
```