# no read permission on 'table' - OleDb & Microsoft Access Database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, oledb

I want to get some information stored inside a Access Database with C#.

This is my Code:

```
using System.Data.OleDb;

OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(
       @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\tmp\bch\data.mdb;Persist Security Info=False"
);

connection.Open();

OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT DesignId from Design WHERE Design='Bamboo'", connection);
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
int? id = null;
while (reader.Read())
{
   id = int.Parse(reader[1].ToString()!);
}

connection.Close();
```

I tried to connect with a OleDbConnection, which works perfectly fine, but i can't get any data from the Database, i always get the following error:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Record(s) cannot be read; no read permission on 'Design'.'

I am able to open the .mdb file by hand and look at the data, but if i execute the code with the same user, it doesn't work...

In some threads i saw the solution to grant the select command to the user first, like this:

```
OleDbCommand grantCommand = new OleDbCommand("GRANT SELECT ON TABLE Design TO Admin", connection);
grantCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Unfortinately this throws another exception and i don't know what to do...

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Cannot open the Microsoft Access database engine workgroup information file.'

Comment: Where can i execute such SQL-Commands in MS-Access?

Comment: If i try to execute this: `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "GRANT SELECT ON Design TO Admin;"` The following error appears: "You don't have the necessary permissions to use the " object."

Comment: _SELECT DesignId from Design WHERE Design='Bamboo'_: Why is the table name (*Design*) in the where clause?

Comment: I would fire up the query builder in Access, and make sure you SQL works. As pointed out, you have a table called Design, and inside there is a column ALSO called design? This of course is legal, but we just trying to make sure that the query as posted can and will work. So, I would open up access, create a new query, flip into SQL view, and type in (or paste in) that SQL like this: SELECT DesignId from Design WHERE Design='Bamboo'

Comment: Yes, there is a Design Field inside the Design table (Don't ask me why, this db is originally from 2003). I tried to do it with the query builer and it works, the generated sql from the query builder is: `SELECT Design.DesignId FROM Design WHERE (("Design"='Bamboo'));`. I tried exactly this query inside C# and there is still the same exception occuring, so i don't think the problem is the query itself...

Comment: NO! NO!, your query is NOT (("Design"='Bamboo')) and that is NOT what you were told to paste into the query builder. You are to paste into the SQL view of the query builder the SAME SQL you are using in code. That means: SELECT DesignId from Design WHERE Design='Bamboo'

Comment: There is not, and was not, and there is NOT to be double quotes around that column name. Use Design, or [Design] for the column name, but out of the blue adding double quotes around that column is HUGE CHANGE and a very different SQL query.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal That query i mentioned was generated by the query builder (I don't know where the double quotes came from...). However i tried my original sql query inside the query builder and it works and also the other way around with the original sql query generated from the query builder. It does not work in c#...

Comment: The following may be of interest: [How do I access an Access database protected by a username/password in Access workgroups via Jet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622502/how-do-i-access-an-access-database-protected-by-a-username-password-in-access-wo)

Comment: Do any SQL queries work, or just this one does not work? In other words, none, zero and any and all SQL queries in your code don't work, or just this one? I mean, if nothing works, then we have a larger issue, and you perhaps don't have the Access (ACE) data engine installed on your computer. You don't mention what version of Visual Studio, and you don't mention what version of Access you have. However, see my answer below as to setting up a valid connection.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the first step is to setup a working connection.

So, in the project, let's add a new connection to the Access database.

It also not quite clear why a mdb is being used in place of an accDB file, but the mdb file format should work, but very "older" mdb files often can't be read/used by ACE data engine, and you have to choose + use the JET data engine.

So, in project settings, add a new connection.

[image]

And don't forget in above to hit the Advanced button, as you want to choose (or check and verify) that you picked ACE in place of JET. However, as noted, for a mdb file, you CAN use JET, but let's for now go with the ACE data engine.

So, clicking on Advanced in above, we can look at (and check) if we choose ACE data engine.

Thus, on advanced tab, check this setting:

[image]

You will also note that I did NOT use the test connection button. The reason why is I am using vs2022, and vs2022 is a x64 bit product, but my office/Access install is a x32 bit version of office.

You MUST SET and MUST MATCH the bit size of your .net project to that of the version of office/Access that you have installed.

So, that is this setting:

[image]

Thus, you can not (should not) use ANY CPU, and you MUST force the project to match the bit size of Access that you are using.

Ok, so with the above setting, then we can now say pull some data.

(I would test pulling some data first before trying to update some data).

So, a form with a button and a DataGridView.

Code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DataTable rstHotels = new DataTable();

    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.AccessDB))
    {
        string strSQL
            = @"SELECT FirstName, LastName, City, HotelName, Description
                FROM tblHotelsA
                ORDER BY HotelName";

        using (OleDbCommand cmdSQL = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            rstHotels.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader()); 
            dataGridView1.DataSource = rstHotels;
        }
    }            
}
```

We have this result:

[image]

Note that if you using a version of Visual studio before vs2022, then the test connection button WILL work, but in vs2022, the test connection button when creating the connect as per above will NOT work unless you are running/using the x64 bit version of Access.

So, follow the above steps, and setup ONE connection that you can thus use throughout your application.

Comment: Because of time consumption, i needed to move on and i just exported the data as an csv  by hand. This works for me, as is just need to migrate the data once... I did not test your solution, but thanks for the effort!
Maybe anotherone can use your solution.